# Translate Teradata DATE function (division/extract and sum) into BigQuery

Tags: sql, function, date, google-bigquery, teradata

I have this code in Teradata that reads "x_date/100+190000". So from my understanding it removes the 'day' portion from DATE and then adds an INT number of days. Now I have to translate the same into BigQuery but can't see how.

edit: so what I have is a SELECT statement that includes the "x_date" field, which has a DATE format. It contains a list of dates in the form of 'yyyy-mm-dd'. The query reads something like:

```
SELECT x_date/100+190000
FROM x_table
```

and the field has this sort of rows:

```
| '2022-06-06' |
| '2020-03-06' |
| '2019-09-01' |
| '2028-05-06' |
```

What I don't understand exactly is what this functions are doing in Teradata.

My expected output should be in DATE format and should be copying (in BigQuery), whatever the Teradata function is doing to the field.

Comment: can you add data to your questiion and wanted result, different databases handles dates diffferently, so a direct transformation isn't needed

Comment: just edited with some new info, ty!

Comment: and what would be the result of that rows?

Comment: In Teradata, dividing a date by 100, and adding 190000 to the result of that, is an incredibly over complicated way to get a date as YYYYMM.

Comment: Yes, it's taking advantage of Teradata's legacy "integerdate" format and would be equivalent to standard SQL `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM x_date)*100+EXTRACT(MONTH FROM x_date)`

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m', x_date)
FROM x_table
```